# Bamboo cloud checkout directory

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo

I'm trying to set up Bamboo with my BitBucket Git repository. I want Bamboo to:

Build my .NET solution
Run tests
Checkout the code on AWS when all tests has passed
I have made a job in Bamboo and added my BitBucket repository to it, set up the above tasks and it seems like all I need now is to set the checkout directory.

Having read the documentation provided by Atlassian about Bamboo, it says that the default checkout directory is where Bamboo is installed. However, since this is a Bamboo Cloud service, I have no idea where this directory is located. Also, it should checkout the code on my Amazon web server (AWS).

So the question is: how do I tell Bamboo to check out my code on AWS? Can't seem to find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Do you have agent installed on AWS ? if yes, then only you can checkout on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Bamboo plan to run on particular agent. go to Bamboo->Agents. Select AWS agent and click on **Dedicate Agent**  and select name of build plan which is supposed to run on that agent.  Next time, when you run this plan, it will automatically run AWS agent.  You can configure different stages to run on different agents too. 
Also, if you any agent is dedicated , then it will not allow any other job to run on it.